# Allow Customer Portal Self-Registration

Tags: customer-portal

I added Allow Customer Portal Self-Registration field to my contact page layout. Even though i added this option to page layout, it is not visible while i am creating a contact record. Do i need any extra permissions from  assigned profile?

please help me

Thanking you
KS Kumaar

[image: Page Layout which i added]

[image: contact creation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the field level security permission for Contact Object for your profile.

[image]

Comment: Yeah @Devendra, You are correct.
Thank you for you Help...